# Does displaying rss feeds in different blogs help get indexed and increase page rank?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, rss, ranking

I have a number of blogs that I run. One of them is old and gets good traffic so what I did is that I have placed the rss of all of the blogs onto the sidebar of each. I was wondering if this is good for SEO in terms of getting indexed faster and getting more page rank as my page rank of the old blog will flow through them into the new ones. Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It doesn't work that way. Displaying content from other websites will not help you get ranked faster or rank better. Links from other websites help with indexing rates and page ranking, but displaying duplicate content does not.

Comment: No, don't take me wrong. All of the sites are mine. I am just displaying the rss as links. You can have a look at the rightmost sidebar of http://www.startupsandfinance.com/

Comment: It doesn't matter if the sites are yours or not. This just isn't going to do anything SEO wise for you. It may be good for promoting each site though.

Comment: Wouldn't the page rank flow through each of them?

Comment: PageRank (one word) flows through links only. So unless you're cross-linking those sites PageRank will not be a factor in this in any way.